# Is it possible to detect a date change on a JCalendar JDateChooser field?

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I'd like to detect when the date is changed in a [JDateChooser](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html) field so that I can update another field.

Is this possible? And if so where should I be starting? I've already looked at the documentation and unfortunately there are no methods for adding something like an ActionListener or StateChangeListener (my first thoughts).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar`](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JCalendar.html) inherits a `listenerList` from `JComponent` and it implements `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`. I'd add a listener and see what comes though.

Edit: I think you can use `addPropertyChangeListener()` the same way `JCalendar` does.

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
chooser.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            if ("date".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
                System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()
                    + ": " + (Date) e.getNewValue());
            }
        }
    });
this.add(chooser);
```

Comment: +1 `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser` is a good example of doing this.

Comment: @trashgod yes sorry I'm using the JDateChooser. I know it has an actionPerformed method but I'm pretty rusty with event handling in Java! I'm used to having an addXListener method to hand. How would I go about attaching a generic listener hook to that method?

Comment: @ghickman: The example is right for the current version, 1.3.3; it looks like the posted API is 1.2.1.

Comment: @trashgod: you're right!

@Catalina Island: Thanks for the example, it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but [`addDateListener(DateListener listener)`](http://flib.sourceforge.net/JCalendar/doc/api/org/freixas/jcalendar/JCalendar.html#addDateListener%28org.freixas.jcalendar.DateListener%29) looks appropriate.

Comment: That does look good but unfortunately I'm not using that JCalendar (hadn't thought there might be two!).  I'm using the toedter.com one: http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/index.html