# JCalendar getting date

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

In my project I am using `com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar` class. But I do not know how can I get date when date is chosen.

JDateChooser and JXDatePicker met my need. There is a code that provides date when a date is chosen from JDateChooser.

```
JDateChooser picker=new JDateChooser();

picker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            setDate(picker.getDate());
        }
 });
```

Comment: Hi. I am not familiar with this class. But I have tried [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx/) were is fantastic JXDatePicker. Which should do what you want. PS: Try to provide us with a link to your class then someone can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will check SwingX now. The JCalender Class javadoc :http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JCalendar.html

Comment: Boro how can I thank you I do not know. Thank you very much. JXDatePicker class met what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely want `addPropertyChangeListener()`, but you need to check `getNewValue()`. There's a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156305/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-date-change-on-a-jcalendar-jdatechooser-field/4157956#4157956).

Comment: +1 for a real solution not just an alternative as in my case :)

Comment: More correctly: ((Calendar) evt.getNewValue()).getTime()

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with this class. But I have tried [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx/) were is fantastic JXDatePicker. Which should do what you want.

Here you can see [introduction to the JXDatePicker](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html) where are nice images showing its capability etc.

PS: Try to provide us with a link to your class then someone can take a look at it.

All the best, Boro.

Comment: Can you suggest a link? Something with a picture might be appealing.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for pointing that out. I thought the link was there, my bad. Now there is link to SwingX library + some JXDatePicker intro which was helpful to me when I was starting using it. All good

Comment: Sweet! The screen shot is especially helpful for future reference. +1, btw.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDatChooser.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                //some stuff
            }
        });
```

Comment: addChangeListener method does not exist in JCalendar class

Comment: http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#propertyChange%28java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent%29

Comment: but that's long time and I used sourceCode (and there I must changed Focus, i18, add Fore/BackGround, disabled Color and put something correctly to the EDT)

Answer (score 0):

Have not used it myself, but according the javadoc:

http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/com/toedter/calendar/JCalendar.html

there seems to be a getDate() method. Does not this work?

Comment: It works but there has to be correct event occurrence. Thats which event occurs when choosing day ? I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getDate() method ? I think it will easy your requested mission.

Answer (score 0):

```
JCalendar cal = new JCalendar();
JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
label.setText(cal.getDate().toString());
      cal.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
              label.setText(cal.getDate().toString());
          }
      });
```