# How to use JCalendar to select an element of my array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, calendar, jcalendar

I have a 3D array that contains 38 years, 12 months, and 31 entries for each month (regardless of how many days in that month). Like so: `array[38][12][31]`. I also have a JCalendar that is doing nothing now except looking pretty, and the JCalendar has a button underneath. How would I make it so that I can select a date in the calendar, then press the button and it returns the element of my array that would correspond to that date?

Something like

```
if(buttonPressed){
    year = chosenYear - 1975;
    month = chosenMonth;
    day = chosenDay;

    System.out.print(array[year][month][day]);
}
```

thanks guys.

Comment: 1) please which one from JCalendars

Comment: 2) (if by Kai Toedter) for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: 3) put (all good JCalendars has class for XxxCellEditor) all JCalendars to JTable, then you can forgot for any type of Arrays, XxxTableModel returns any of changes or value from elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the selected `Date` in a `PropertyChangeListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157956/230513). Once you have the `date`, you can get the year, month and day from a `Calendar`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

`Calendar.MONTH` is already zero-based, but `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is not; and you'll need to adjust the year to your baseline.

Comment: You've definitely set me on the right track, thank you!
I'm currently trying to set integers to the selected date as you've demonstrated, but I get the error `incompatible types. Required: JCalendar. Found: Calendar`

Any ideas? :)

Comment: You have to cast `Date date = (Date) e.getNewValue()`.

Comment: It's aliiiiive! Thanks so much both of you! @CatalinaIsland