# How to detect change of date in JDateChooser/JCalendar

Tags: java, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I am using JDateChooser with JCalendar in application. User should choose the date in date chooser and date should be updated in JTextFieldDateEditor. However, I can't seem to get the PropertyChangeListener to work.

I have checked it on stackoverflow as well, found [Is it possible to detect a date change on a JCalendar JDateChooser field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156305/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-date-change-on-a-jcalendar-jdatechooser-field) which seems to be the exact same problem as I am having. I copied the code through from there, but I still get 'cannot find symbol - class PropertyChangeListener' error. I imported whole awt.event and JCalendar libraries. I am absolutely clueless as to what is wrong with my code.

Here's what I have written so far

```
datum = new Date ();
klik = new JDateChooser (datum)

klik.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) 
    {
        if ("date".equals(e.getPropertyName())) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()
                + ": " + (Date) e.getNewValue());
        }
    }
});
```

which is basically copy-paste from the link above, but it seems reasonable to me

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If you hope to get a good response to this question, you have to show some code to explain your efforts so far.

Comment: please post the whole exception (error) you get.

Comment: The error is 'cannot find symbol - class PropertyChangeListener' - it is usually thrown when the symbol has not been declared. I am using BlueJ IDE

Comment: put this on top of your code `import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`

Comment: did it, hasn't helped

Comment: For better help please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the issue and we can copy - paste and compile it, so we can give you better help