# jDateChooser - Never updates with selection

Tags: java, eclipse, jcalendar

I'm trying to pull in a date so I can work with it in SQL.  I put the jDateChooser on the screen and use it to define a string.  Because it starts out with no value (null), it throws Null Pointer Exception.  I initialize the JDateChooser with `compdate.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());`
This sets the date to today and that is the value I get returned when I pull in the string.  The code is below and I would love to resolve this.  I'm guessing it is from my ignorance about when the update should be firing...

```
    JDateChooser compdate = new JDateChooser();
    compdate.setDateFormatString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    compdate.setBounds(26, 75, 144, 23);
    compdate.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
    String jcalval = (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")).format(compdate.getDate());
    panelReporting.add(compdate);
    System.out.println(jcalval);
```

Comment: You can add a listener like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157956/261156).

Comment: Thanks so much Greg.  I got it to update the date, but when I pull the date using the jcalval statement, it shows today's date.  Not sure where to go from here. The statement is after the update, but then again, I don't really know the order it is processing the update.

Comment: And I believe it's resolved as I just had to move the updated string = to another event.  IT's working now, thanks so much guys!!

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP reported that he fixed the issue by adding a listener as suggested in the comments and the linked question:

```
    compdate.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {

             if ("date".equals(e.getPropertyName())) 
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getPropertyName()
                        + ": " + (Date) e.getNewValue());
                }
            }
        });
```

(This was posted in the question, where it doesn’t belong; I just took it out into an answer.)